# Conditional probability of a player playing table tennis given that player is playing chess.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

A games club has 80 members out of whom 70 play chess, 45 play table tennis, and 35 play both chess and table tennis. If a member of the club is randomly chosen, find the conditional probability that he or she plays table tennis given that he or she plays chess.

$\textbf{IIUC}:$

$P(E|F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)}$

$P(E \cap F) = 35$

$P(F) = 70$

$P(E|F) = \frac{35}{70} = 0.5$

Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Comment: Well, $P(F) = 70 > 1$ is certainly wrong... but replacing those with the proper values your answer is correct

Comment: Just  change  probability to 35/80 from 35 and 70/80 from 70. Then it’s  fine.